# Why using a @Many-to-one in JPA entity relationships?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, javabeans

My question might look silly. I am new to JPA and trying to understand the underlying concepts of it. I found out that there is a @Many-to-one entity relationship that can be used there. My question is why someone would want to use this while have @One-to-many relationship?
I mean, having the latter one is enough to know the relationship and sending queries right?
if not please explain. Maybe the idea that I have about these two relationships are completely wrong. Please provide a scenario as an example so I understand better.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OneToMany` is used to map collections. If you want this relation to be bidirectional then you need to add a `ManyToOne` mapping on the other side.

With Hibernate mapping : Person N <---> 1 Address

```
<class name="Person">
    <id name="id" column="personId"/>
    <many-to-one name="address" column="addressId"/>
</class>

<class name="Address">
    <id name="id" column="addressId"/>
    <set name="people">
        <key column="addressId"/>
        <one-to-many class="Person"/>
    </set>
</class>
```

`ManyToOne` can also be used to map a dependency between 2 objects. In this case if you want the relation to be bidirectional then you need to add a `OneToOne` mapping on the other side.

With Hibernate mapping : Person 1 <---> 1 Address

```
<class name="Person">
    <id name="id" column="personId"/>
    <many-to-one name="address" column="addressId" unique="true"/>
</class>

<class name="Address">
    <id name="id" column="addressId"/>
   <one-to-one name="person" property-ref="address"/>
</class>
```

Answer (score 1):

`@ManyToOne` and `@OneToMany`are both part of the same concept used to describe the two sides of a single bidirectional relationship.

If you want the relationship to be unidirectional - i.e. one of the entities cannot traverse to the other, you can use one of the annotations. To decide which one, you will have to decide which entity should know about the relation and which should not.

But often you want a bidirectional relation - then you use both.